# Unable to load shared library 'onnxruntime' or one of its dependencies on Mac OS

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, ml.net

I try to run my program but it gives me the exception attached below. Can you please help me? I use **Visual Studio 2019** on **Mac** just in case you need this information. I have tried installing **"mono-libgdiplus"** package from **brew**, but that did not help me. I searched for some more information regarding this problem, and found out the next package: **"runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing"**. This also did not resolve my issue. I would be very glad if you could help me out!

[image]

I would also like to show that **"onxxruntime.dll"** exists. You can check it from the image below:

[image]

Program, in fact, can access **"onxxruntime.dll"** as seen from the code below:

[image]

Comment: The error says that it can't load the *native* library `onnxruntime` or it's dependencies. That's not a `.dll`, that's a `.dylib` on macOS. You should look for a ` libonnxruntime.dylib`. Running `otool -L`  on it will tell if you some other native dependency is missing. Might also be a good idea to do what the error suggests and set the  `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` environment variable to see what the actual error while loading the native library is.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do that.